# Flutter FutureBuilder mixing up data

Tags: flutter, firebase

I have the following widget, where I am trying to render by default a FutureBuilder, but if the user uses the search bar I wanted to display another FutureBuilder that displays the data, for some reason when the FutureBuilder that display the search results is getting the snapshot of the other Future Builder

TLDR;
First FutureBuilder gets the data from the second

```dart
class Search extends StatefulWidget {
  const Search({super.key});

  @override
  State<Search> createState() => _SearchState();
}

class _SearchState extends State<Search> {
  final TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();
  bool displayResults = false;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    searchController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor,
        title: TextFormField(
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Search for an user',
          ),
          controller: searchController,
          onFieldSubmitted: (String _) {
            setState(() {
              displayResults = true;
            });
          },
        ),
        centerTitle: false,
      ),
      body: displayResults
          ? FutureBuilder(
              //this displays the search results
              future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection(userCollection)
                  .where(
                    'username',
                    isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: searchController.text,
                  )
                  .get(),
              builder: (context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snap) {
                if (!snap.hasData) {
                  const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snap.data != null ? snap.data!.docs.length : 0,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    // this is expected to be of type user and
                    // from the user collection
                    // but for some reason is of type post
                    print(snap.data!.docs[index].data());
                    model.User user =
                        model.User.fromSnap(snap.data!.docs[index]);
                    return ListTile(
                      leading: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                          user.getProfilePicture(),
                        ),
                      ),
                      title: Text(user.username),
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            )
          : FutureBuilder(
              //this is displays user posts
              future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection(postsCollection)
                  .orderBy('datePublished')
                  .limit(20)
                  .get(),
              builder: (context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
                return GridView.custom(
                  gridDelegate: SliverQuiltedGridDelegate(
                    crossAxisCount: 4,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 2,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 2,
                    repeatPattern: QuiltedGridRepeatPattern.inverted,
                    pattern: [
                      const QuiltedGridTile(3, 2),
                      const QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
                      const QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
                      const QuiltedGridTile(2, 2),
                    ],
                  ),
                  childrenDelegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                    (context, index) => snapshot.data != null &&
                            index < snapshot.data!.docs.length
                        ? Image.network(
                            snapshot.data!.docs[index]['imageUrl'],
                          )
                        : null,
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

types definitions

```
class User {
  final String username;
  final String email;
  final String profilePicture;
  final String uid;
  final String bio;
  final List followers;
  final List following;
  const User(
      {required this.username,
      required this.uid,
      required this.profilePicture,
      required this.bio,
      required this.email,
      required this.followers,
      required this.following});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "username": username,
        "uid": uid,
        "email": email,
        "profilePicture": profilePicture,
        "bio": bio,
        "followers": followers,
        "following": following,
      };

  static User fromSnap(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    var snap = snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

    return User(
        username: snap['username'],
        uid: snap['uid'],
        profilePicture: snap['profilePicture'],
        bio: snap['bio'],
        email: snap['email'],
        followers: snap['followers'],
        following: snap['following']);
  }

  String getProfilePicture() {
    if (profilePicture.isEmpty) {
      return defaulProfilePicture;
    } else {
      return profilePicture;
    }
  }
}
```

```
class Post {
  final String uid;
  final String postId;
  final String imageUrl;
  final String description;
  final DateTime datePublished;
  final List likes;
  final int likeCount;
  const Post({
    required this.uid,
    required this.description,
    required this.imageUrl,
    required this.datePublished,
    required this.likes,
    required this.postId,
    required this.likeCount,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "uid": uid,
        "description": description,
        "imageUrl": imageUrl,
        "datePublished": datePublished,
        "likes": likes,
        "likeCount": likeCount,
        "postId": postId,
      };

  static Post fromSnap(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    var snap = snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

    return Post(
      uid: snap['uid'],
      description: snap['description'],
      imageUrl: snap['imageUrl'],
      datePublished: snap['datePublished'],
      likes: snap['likes'],
      likeCount: snap['likeCount'],
      postId: snap['postId'],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try adding ValueKey to both the FutureBuilders.

Answer (score 0):

As Rahul mentioned in the comments adding a key to each FutureBuilder fix the issue, it would be like this in the code

```dart
  final Key searchBuilderKey = const Key('Search Builder');
  final Key postsBuilderKey = const Key('Posts Builder');
```

and in each FutureBuilder

```dart
         FutureBuilder(
              key: searchBuilderKey,
              ...
```

```dart
         FutureBuilder(
              key: postsBuilderKey,
              ...
```